# Changing Font Style in class rather than interaction and preventing repetitive code

Tags: c#

I'm getting back into coding (I have little experience just some education). I am trying to create a hello world program where you can change all the aspects of the font and am currently stuck on changing the font styles in a class.

The reason I want to do this in a class is because I don't want to repeat the same code behind each check box for Bold, Italics and Underline. So far I have managed to get a basic concept together but I feel its long and lengthy and can either be shortened or at least made into some form of class to be called when needed. This is what I have so far:

```
    private void chkItalics_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkItalics.Checked == true)
        {
            Italics = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Italics = false;
        }

        if ((Italics == true) && (Bold == false) && (Underline == false))
        {
            lblHello.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontType, FontSize, FontStyle.Italic);
        }
        else if ((Italics == true) && (Bold == true) && (Underline == false))
        {
            lblHello.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontType, FontSize, FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Bold);
        }
        else if ((Italics == true) && (Bold == true) && (Underline == true))
        {
            lblHello.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontType, FontSize, FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
        }
        else if ((Italics == false) && (Bold == true) && (Underline == false))
        {
            lblHello.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontType, FontSize, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
        else if ((Italics == false) && (Bold == true) && (Underline == true))
        {
            lblHello.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontType, FontSize, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
        }
        else if ((Italics == false) && (Bold == false) && (Underline == true))
        {
            lblHello.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontType, FontSize, FontStyle.Underline);
        }
        else
        {
            lblHello.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontType, FontSize, FontStyle.Regular);
        }
```

As said fairly messy and bulky, any help would be very much appreciated. I did look into doing a Switch instead of all the if statements but could not figure out a way to get all of the above into it.

But most important is trying to get this into a class as I have not had any luck there as the classes in C# do not seem to like to reference form controls and variables from outside the class.

Comment: You can also try posting on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want tips on how to write cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;

if (Underline) { fontStyle |= FontStyle.Underline; }
// ..

lblHello.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontType, FontSize, fontStyle);
```

I would bind the events to a single check changed handler. You could also introduce some computed properties:

```
public bool Underline { get { return chkUnderline.Checked; } }
```